# Cannot open text file Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files

I am trying to test a program using a text file. I do not have much experience in text files, so I have some problems trying to open the text file. The tester I wrote is written below:

```
public class TestGetPlanet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkGetPlanet();
    }

    private static void checkEquals(double d1, double d2, String label) {
        if (d1 == d2) {
            System.out.println("PASS: " + label + ": " + d1 + " equal to " + d2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAIL: " + label + ": " + d1 + " not equal to " + d2);
        }
    }

    private static void checkStringEquals(String s1, String s2, String label) {

        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("PASS: " + label + ": " + s1 + " equal to " + s2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAIL: " + label + ": " + s1 + " not equal to " + s2);
        }
    }

    private static void checkGetPlanet() {
        System.out.println("Checking getPlanet...");

        In in = new In("data/planets.txt");
        in.readInt();
        in.readDouble();

        Planet p = Simulator.getPlanet(in);

        checkEquals(p.x, 1.496e11, "x");
        checkEquals(p.y, 0.0, "y");
        checkEquals(p.xVelocity, 0.0, "xVelocity");
        checkEquals(p.yVelocity, 29800.0, "yVelocity");
        checkEquals(p.xAccel, 0.0, "xAccel");
        checkEquals(p.yAccel, 0.0, "yAccel");
        checkStringEquals(p.img, "earth.gif", "image");
    }
}
```

The text file I want to open (`planets.txt`) is:

```
     1.4960e+11  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  2.9800e+04  5.9740e+24    earth.gif
     2.2790e+11  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  2.4100e+04  6.4190e+23     mars.gif
     5.7900e+10  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  4.7900e+04  3.3020e+23  mercury.gif
     0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  1.9890e+30      sun.gif
     1.0820e+11  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  3.5000e+04  4.8690e+24    venus.gif
    [!] Your program should not read this line, as all 5 planets were already                     listed
and there is no further information to be specified. So you can put comments here.
This file contains the inner 4 planets of our solar system and the sun.
```

Comment: "I have some problems trying to open the text file" - please elaborate.

Comment: When I run this program on command line, it gives me this error: `Could not open data/planets.txt`

Comment: How exactly does `In` class use `"data/planets.txt"`? Where is your `data` directory located? Are you sure it contains `planets.txt` file?